# Two functions whose order can't be equated - big O notation

Tags: asymptotics, relations

Our teacher talked today in the class about big O notation, and about order relations.

she mentioned that the set of order of magnitude, is not linear

Meaning, there are function $f,g$ such that $f$ is not $O(g)$ and $g$ is not $O(f)$, but she gave no such example and im having trouble coming up with one.

Just out of sheer curiosity, could anyone come up with such 2 functions?

Comment: There are tons of examples, you can just put together piecewise bits that alternate between classical functions one which is bigger, one which is smaller.

Comment: Anything not piecewise? again, just curious.

Comment: There are plenty, but it's really easy to see with the one I posted. You can always put in wiggly functions to push them down (eg. the classical trig functions) but they're essentially the same idea.

Comment: Perhaps somewhat of an open question - But does this have any implication towards computer science? Is there an algorithm that runs at $x^2\sin(x)$?

Comment: That wouldn't make any sense, that function is sometimes negative.

Really the implication is simple:  not all algorithms are comparable in terms of runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x^2\sin x$ and $g(x)=x.$

Comment: Yes ofcourse...Trigonometric functions work.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x^2 & 2n\le x<2n+1 \\ 1 & 2n+1\le x < 2n+2\end{cases}$$ and $g(x) = x$.